# <li> Elements Not Sorting Correctly in <ul>?

Tags: php, sorting

In the link provided below you will see "Brand Images" when scrolling downward. Continue to scroll & notice that all list elements (Brand Images) are alphabetical within unordered list tags & appearing in (4) rows accordingly from Left to Right from (A-Z).

Well, if you scroll all the way down you see the last (4) Brand Images (trinaturk, trowbridge, worlds away & zentique) are out of alphabetical order. They should appear at the bottom of row #4 (furthest right). I have manipulated the following code with no success. I just can't figure this out? Thanks for any help!

http://shopcandelabra.com/brands/

Comment: I visited your page with Chrome and your list is in order. I double checked in case I was drunk. (just kidding- stoned) It is in order when I use Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 m. (I am too much of an old fuddy-duddy to be drunk or stoned- senile perhaps)

Answer (score 1):

Your last four items are not within li elements but are within spans outside of any li element. That is why they are not acting like the others.

Answer (score 0):

You should rethink the layout of that part to be a bit more maintainable... Like each logo is a list element (not the columns), with a fixed size, a `border-bottom: 1px solid #000000`, and floated left, with a clearfix after the closing `</ul>` element.

But currently your problem is (as Rob stated before me), the 4 renegades aren't part of the list.